# An electron in a TV tube is beamed horizontally at a speed of 4.3 * 10^6 meters per second

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

An electron in a TV tube is beamed horizontally at a speed of 4.3 * 0^6 meters per second toward the face of the tube 31 cm away. How far will the electron drop before it hits?

(Assume ideal projectile motion, that is, that the electron undergoes constant downward acceleration due to gravity but no other acceleration; assume also that acceleration due to gravity is -9.8 meters per second-squared.)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My homework says my answer is wrong.

This is my work:

30cm = 0.3m

$\frac{0.3}{4.3*10^6}$

d = 4.9 * $(\frac{0.3}{4.3*10^6})^2$

Then to convert from m to fem,

4.9 * $(\frac{0.3}{4.3*10^6})^2$*10^15 = 23.85073012439156300703082747431043807463493780421849648458626

I enter this in, but it says I got it wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe because it is $31$ cm?

Comment: @Arpan thank u so much! oh mygod why did i not catch that? is my approach correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be correct.